# Construct a compressed Response to take advantage of native decompression

Tags: javascript, ajax, brotli

My application bundles some brotli-compresset assets and I want to somehow decompress them using browser itself instead of shipping a decompression library. The best way I could think of to trick browser into doing that is simulating a compressed response, which, unfortunately, doesn't work:

```
// Here's a brotli-compressed JSON
const compressedBytes = new Uint8Array([161,232,7,128,225,60,176,219,56,82,174,50,55,131,242,211,168,22,217,235,218,154,50,66,77,182,205,166,93,90,37,27,71,177,131,132,178,39,139,111,22,157,174,62,78,57,215,150,98,130,73,70,223,18,63,30,0,14,14,57,104,135,68,162,247,46,194,120,39,9,132,46,144,108,191,147,200,106,67,47,244,253,195,243,78,156,106,123,173,29,132,142,15,209,17,230,72,114,152,70,211,188,205,84,49,205,172,101,245,67,59,130,0,116,246,124,222,250,15]);
const headers = new Headers();
headers.append( 'Content-Encoding', 'br' );
headers.append( 'Content-Type', 'application/json' );
const r = new Response( compressedBytes.buffer, { status: 200, statusText: 'OK', headers } );
await r.arrayBuffer(); // Unfortunately just outputs a provided buffer w/o decompressing it
```

I tried to put a request into cache, clone it, but nothing seems to work. Perhaps anyone know a way to achieve native decompression? `DecompressionStream` API is somehow relevant, but it doesn't support brotli and have compatibility issues.

Answer (score 1):

According to [this issue](https://github.com/google/brotli/issues/120), it seems that the brotli decoder included in the browsers is not exposed to JS and that the prefered way for decoding brotli is to use a library (like [brotli.js](https://github.com/foliojs/brotli.js))

`DecompressionStream` API in its current version is not relevant because :

> Compression formats other than "gzip" and "deflate" will not be supported in the first version of the API.

[(source)](https://github.com/wicg/compression/blob/main/explainer.md#non-goals)

[An issue to support brotli has been opened](https://github.com/WICG/compression/issues/34), but I guess you'll have to wait a bit longer ^^